# Global Function Context

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a function called `run ()` but I can't find it in the context of `module.export`. What is the context in which this function is stored?

```
    function run(){


            function run2(){
                console.log(this === global)
                console.log(this === module)
            }

            run2()

        }




  console.log(module.exports)
```

Comment: You didn't add it to `module.exports`, why *would* it be there?

Answer (score 0):

The context is `global`. You have to export it to find it inside `module.export` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
module.exports.run = function() {
    function run2() {
        console.log(this === global)
        console.log(this === module)
    }

    run2()

}

console.log(module.exports)
```